# Alert is coming before response

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this ajax function which validates the user provided key. but the alert comes before the ajax response and due to which if the user provide a wrong key even can get access

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var key = $('#downloadkey').val();
        var dataString = {KEY:key};
        $.ajax({
            url: "/mediabox/home/validate_key",
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,

            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg=="true") 
                {
                   alert("do something");
                }
                else
                {
                   alert("Your download key is either wrong or you didn't provide it.");
                   return false;
                }                        

            }
        });

    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: **What?** I am quite confuzzled....

Comment: with this code, alert will come only when this success call back executed (when it gets  a response from the server page)

Comment: Believe me When I submit the form I suddenly get the alert and while the alert is on my screen I can see that the ajax call is still not complete and the response portion is empty when i click ok on the alert then i see the response

Comment: What do you mean by response portion? What are you using to inspect the response?

Comment: Have a look at the screenshot

Comment: Your popup indicates that your response is not `true`, as being checked for in `msg=="true"`.

Comment: I guess the browser rendering engine is blocked on the alert but the call still has been made, try some console logs to trace the order of events...

Comment: But whn I click on the ok button of alert it says true when i provide the correct key and false when i provide wrong key

Answer (score 0):

What makes you believe the alert is coming before the response? The success handler is only invoked after the response has been successfully received client-side.

To confirm, you can edit your success handler to log the response:

```
success: function(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
   if(msg=="true") 
   {
      alert("do something");
   }
   else
   {
       alert("Your download key is either wrong or you didn't provide it.");
       return false;
   }                        
}
```

Also, if you're using the `return false` to deny access to the user by blocking the HTML action that, won't work due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

The [success](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function is called when the request completes.

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three
>   arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to
>   the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

The code within the success handler will only execute once the AJAX request is completed.  If you are getting an alert before hand then that indicates that the request completed properly.